# connecting two ISPs to my network

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, isp

Hi My network has the following resources:

- 3 ASA-5505 w/site-to-site VPN's
- newly acquired c801F-K9 router
- Exchange Server
- 3 ISP's (soon to be 2) A t-1, DSL, Satellite.
- VOIP Cisco Cme

My goal is to do away with the T1 and use the DSL and Sat.  Because of the latency with the satellite, I would like to have the DSL as gateway for the email and VPNs and the rest of outbound traffic to be handled by the satellite.

Questions:

- Can I just replace my Local ASA-5505 with the C891 and use policy base routing to handle everything?

Comment: Removed the question asking for off-topic, opinion-based answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Policy based routing Configuration helps us to route traffic to destination with reference to source .

With PBR traffic can be only routed . It  has limitation for controlling traffic .

ASA firewall is security device where as inbound and outbound traffic is granually controlled  and monitor traffic by framing security policies in firewalls . C891 has limitations controlling and monitor traffic.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on if you have a block of public IP's (or an ASN) that you want redundant reachability for.  If all you need to do is handle multiple outbound paths for your LAN(s), I would use the router - the new 891 and configure it accordingly.

If you want redundant (multipath) inbound reachability, that's probably going to involve BGP peering with your ISP(s), unless a single ISP provides both links - in which case they can probably set that up for you on their equipment.

Comment: Note that getting an ASN from ARIN requires justification of at least 128 public addresses and the minimum subnet size for BGP between different ISPs is /24. Maintaining the ASN involves an annual cost to ARIN. I'm currently going through the BGP setup process and it's probably not something that someone using 5505s and one Exchange server will be able to justify and want to pay for.

Comment: @ToddWilcox very good to know.  Didn't know that.  What kinda pricetag we talkin for an ASN?  $100/yr, $1,000 yr, $10,000/yr?  ty

Comment: Obviously ARIN serves North America, so the policies and prices may not apply outside of there. We are paying around $500 per year. Not too much, but some organizations could be sticker shocked by that. Plus the ISPs are upcharging us to provide the BGP service on the links (one of them charges $150/month for BGP), plus we had to buy more expensive routers that support BGP (RAM to store the routing table can be a factor) and we have to hire a contractor to do the programming, since it's not just putting in a couple static routes. So it's adding up. And lots of work.